# iOS UITableView with dynamic prototypes and custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have uitableviewcontroller with tableview with dynamic prototypes cell and even I change my cell style to subtitle or something else or I add accessory my cell always shows as basic style cell.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (_dataArray && row < self.dataArray.count) {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.dataArray[row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: There is something I don't understand, maybe someone can explain this. Earlier my app crashed when I show my table view controller, so I had to add this to the viewDidLoad method:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

After that the app did not crash, but it caused that I could not change the cell style. Now I can delete that, my app don't crash and I can change the cell style. Why?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the identifier of the cell in storyboard.

[image]

Also use tags to modifier UI elements from storyboard:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *eventNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
```

Comment: Yes, the identifier is set. I use basic cell style, but when I selected e.g. disclosure indicator as a accessory view, then it did not show. It shows when I delete registering the cell.